# Can I upgrade or downgrade flutter sdk to a specific version?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change from v2.10.1 to v2.10.2. And can it be changed by path or maybe others?

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to 2.10.2, you can simply run

```
flutter version v2.10.2
```

and to downgrade:

```
flutter downgrade
```

`flutter downgrade` only works if you have installed previous version from the same channel. if not, you can run

```
flutter downgrade v2.10.1
```

**UPDATE**

seems like `flutter version` has been depreciated. You could use [fvm](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm) to easily switch between different versions

Comment: I can't use the flutter version v2.10.2. Error: Could not find a command named "version".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

Comment: I already add fvm to my project but there is a warning.

Comment: Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated fvm 2.3.1.